# 'employee does not exist, or bad password’ in Presta Shop

Tags: cookies

New to HTML  and scripting.

I have added a Prestashop to my site and now, when I try to log into the admin panel back end, I get the above error message. I found some info online where they say to post this script: [UPDATE employee SET passwd = md5(””) 
WHERE email = “youremailaddress”;] but do not know where exactly do I need to enter it. I've gone I think to every folder in the config files and do not find anything that looks like that . Can someone help me?
I do know it's a cookie error. I also do not know how to navigate my sql so I navigate using my files folders.

Answer (score 0):

- First open file settings.inc.php in config folder
- then copy and paste the code following "cookie_key", whitout '
  caracters
- Paste in the site http://www.md5.cz/
- Add your password next to pasted password in the window
- Click on the button
- Paste generated passord
- Open database, open "ps_employee” table
- Click on “modify” and Paste password in password window
- Click on execute
- Finally you just have to open the login page and refresh it to access
  to your website.

OR
 this problem may come from folder name with speacial caracters like ', ^, etc... or also spaces in folder name of path

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You have forgotten your password. Just reset your password using the Lost Password link on the admin login page.